# allow html characters on eshop data entry boxes

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a change on the core eshop plugins, since on their forum they don't support core changes I'm posting my question in here.

Maybe is kind of simple however I cannot find the solution, basically I need the product description support html characters. Right now looks like this:

```
 <label for="eshop_product_description"><?php _e('Product Description (For Checkout)','eshop'); ?></label>
 <input id="eshop_product_description" name="eshop_product_description" value="<?php if (isset($eshop_product['description'])) echo $eshop_product['description']; ?>" type="text" size="30"/>
```

Any chances to allow this change on this line w/o touching any other information?

Thanks in advanced.

**UPDATE**

---

Reading a little... (cause that is the problem, we don't read) I found the solution for my problem, "htmlspecialchars_decode" function would do the trick, now I wonder how to close or erase a post in here ^^.

```
 <?php if (isset($eshop_product['details'])) echo htmlspecialchars_decode($eshop_product['details']); ?>
```

Regards

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so your question doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Comment: if you read it more carefully you will notice i did it =)

Comment: Not edit it into question, but create new answer and put it there. That way it can be marked accepted. Otherwise this would forever be question that doesn't have any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a little... (cause that is the problem, we don't read) I found the solution for my problem, "htmlspecialchars_decode" function would do the trick, now I wonder how to close or erase a post in here ^^.

```
 <?php if (isset($eshop_product['details'])) echo htmlspecialchars_decode($eshop_product['details']); ?>
```